# Shell script & csv problem to write in a file

Tags: shell, csv

I try to add information in acsv file with a shell script.

For the moment I add the information, my problem is that the csv file isn't empty at the beginning.

So I would like to put the new information in another column.

But I can't find the way to do this.

here is my code :

> sed -i '1i column3' test.csv
>
> sed -i '2i;;4' test.csv
>
> sed -i '3i;;2' test.csv

The output that I have is

> column 3
>
> ```
>        4
>
>        2
> ```
>
> 1       2
>
> 3       4

And I would like this:

> 1  2    column 3
>
> 3  4    4
>
> ```
>  2
> ```

Do you think it's possible?

thanks

Comment: Do you think you could have posted a proper input file example?

Comment: I'm pretty confused by what you've posted here. I don't see any commas (kind of strange for a CSV :) and I can't figure out what is data, what is commands, and how the output you want relates to the input you've given.

Comment: it's kind of difficult to put a good output/input here. I'll try to explain more.
In my file csv, I have 2 columns which have both 2 lines (first one with 1 / 3 , second one 2 / 4). I would like to add a third column with 3 lines but with my code I can have a third columns but the lines are not good, everything move. In fact the third columns must be on the same line than column 1 & 2.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you wrote in your example:

```
sed -i '1s/.*/& column3/' test.csv
sed -i '2s/.*/& 4/' test.csv
```

with awk (if you want to use space as a separator just leave out the "-vOFS=, -F," part):

```
awk -vOFS=, -F, 'NR==1 {$3="col3"; print;}' test.csv
awk -vOFS=, -F, 'NR==2 {$3=4; print;}' test.csv
```

Change the first column:

```
awk -vOFS=, -F, 'NR==1 {$1="col1"; print;}' test.csv
```

Insert a column between the 2:

```
awk -vOFS=, -F, 'NR==1 {print $1,"newcol",$2;}' test.csv
```

Comment: Thanks, I try it. With this, it stay on the same line but in the second column, how can I choose which column I want (here the third one) thanks

Comment: @tranen: It should add a column in the end separated with a space like in your example. If you want to use ',' as a separator try "sed -i '1s/.*/&,column3/' test.csv". If you want to change other columns sed can be a little uncomfortable. IMHO you might be better off with awk.